# Datepicker click event not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

A quick question that I can't wrap my head around.

We have a simple Datepicker (jQuery UI) with a `click` event on the `td` and  nothing else. But no matter what I try the click event will not fire.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/s63y1w6h/

The click event is delaged, since the html changes each time a `td` is clicked, but the same "nothing" happens again.

As to why I need to click the `a`, I need the `td` data attributes, text and its offeset, which will be harder to get from the onSelect `method`.

Any idea how to fire up the click event?

Comment: Just check the jQuery-ui library, where you can see `if ( handled ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
  }` this prevents the default action and event bubbling ......

Comment: I thought it will be something like this, thanks for the info,

Comment: I had some free time, so decided to give it a try(sadly on the `onSelect` method due to @PranavCBalan comments)  https://jsfiddle.net/5qwgoxyL/

Comment: Thanks @KaushalNiraula. But I will probably go with `mousedown` event in order to decrease the spaghetti code, but nonetheless it's a nice solution.

Comment: @KaushalNiraula I fallback to your solution, since the `mousedown` event was breaking other code logic. If you add it as a separate answer I will accept it. :) 10x.

Comment: @drip done. And glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `onSelect` to fire your logic when a day is clicked

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  onSelect:function(dt,obj){
    var day = parseInt(dt.substring(3,5));
    var td;
    $("td>a").each(function(index,elm){
     if(parseInt($(elm).html()) === day){
       td = $(elm).parent();
       return;
      }
    })
    console.log(td)
    alert("You're welcome!!!")
  }
});
```

Wrote some hack logic to get the `td` based on the day selected

Working [plnkr](https://jsfiddle.net/5qwgoxyL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Your code here
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s63y1w6h/1/

EDIT:
Try to put your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            //your code here
        }  
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s63y1w6h/2

Comment: This doesn't work once you click a `td` or change the month (since the html is removed and added once again by default). You must delage your event.

Comment: @drip well in that case you can use `onSelect` from `datepicker` option. https://jsfiddle.net/s63y1w6h/2/